# If $(5,8)$ is a point on the graph of $f(x)$, find $2f(x)-9$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $(5,8)$ is a point on the graph of $f(x)$, find

a.) a point on $f(x-2)$

b.) a point on $3f(x)$

c.) a point on $2f(x)-9$

d.) a point on $0.5f(x+1)+3$

e.) a point on $f(7x)$

I think I understand this but am conflicted at times. Parts a,b,e are fine as they have only one operation, but I don't understand the ones that have multiple operations. Here is why.

For part c, it is say to multiply the $y$ value by $2$ and subtract the $y$ value by $9$. But it seems like you do not get the same answer if you do each step in a different order.

$8 \cdot 2 = 16$ and $16 - 9 =7$, but $8-9 = -1$ and $-1 \cdot 2 = -2$. So are these two different solutions to this problem, or do you have to do order of operations to get the right solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hint, you know that $f(5)=8$.

If $g(x)=f(x-2)$ what is $g(7)$?

If $g(x)=3f(x)$ what is $g(5)$?

If $g(x)=2f(x)-9$ what is $g(5)$?

If $g(x)=0.5f(x+1)+3$ what is $g(4)$?

If $g(x)=f(7x)$ what is $g(\frac{5}{7})$?